# MVC 5 drop down list value not passing into controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have created a dropdownlistfor in my Product Details view that has 5 hard coded values (1,2,3,4,5) and when I'm selecting the value I want to then pass it into the AddToCartWithQuantity method in the ShoppingCart controller and then into the Shopping cart model's method of the same name when I click the add to cart button but when I add the item to the cart the quantity comes up as 0.

My Product Details View:

```
@model BigVisionGames.Models.Products

@{
ViewBag.Title = "Details";
Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h3>Product:  @Model.ProductName</h3>

<div id="product-details">
<p>
    <em>Price: </em>
    £@($"{Model.Price:F}")
</p>

<div style="color:black">
    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.ChosenQuantity, new 
List<SelectListItem>
 {
            new SelectListItem{ Text="1", Value = "1" },
            new SelectListItem{ Text="2", Value = "2" },
            new SelectListItem{ Text="3", Value = "3" },
            new SelectListItem{ Text="4", Value = "4" },
            new SelectListItem{ Text="5", Value = "5" }
        })

    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ChosenQuantity, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
</div>

@if (Model.StockLevel == 0)
{
    <p style="color:red">This item is currently out of stock!</p>
}
else
{
    <p class="btn">
        @Html.ActionLink("Add to cart", "AddToCartWithQuantity", "ShoppingCart", new { id = Model.Id}, "")
    </p>
}
```

ShoppingCartController method

```
        public ActionResult AddToCartWithQuantity(int id, Products productModel)

    {

        // Retrieve the product from the database
        var addedproduct = storeDB.Products
            .Single(product => product.Id == id);

        // Add it to the shopping cart
        var cart = ShoppingCart.GetCart(this.HttpContext);

        cart.AddToCartWithQuantity(addedproduct, productModel.ChosenQuantity);

        // Go back to the main store page for more shopping
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

ShoppingCart Model method for setting the chosen quantity

```
public void AddToCartWithQuantity(Products product, int chosenQuantity)
    {
        // Get the matching cart and product instances
        var cartItem = storeDB.Carts.SingleOrDefault(
            c => c.CartId == ShoppingCartId
                 && c.ProductId == product.Id);

        if (cartItem == null)
        {
            // Create a new cart item if no cart item exists
            cartItem = new Cart
            {
                ProductId = product.Id,
                CartId = ShoppingCartId,
                Quantity = chosenQuantity,
                DateCreated = DateTime.Now
            };
            storeDB.Carts.Add(cartItem);
        }
        else
        {
            // If the item does exist in the cart, 
            // then add one to the quantity
            cartItem.Quantity++;
        }

        // Save changes
        storeDB.SaveChanges();
    }
```

Comment: Your current code does not do what you want. It renders an anchor tag. You need to either do a form submit or an ajax post or send to the action method.

Comment: Where is your form?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your current code is rendering an anchor tag and clicking on which will do a GET request with the id in the querystring. If you want to send the selected value from the quantity dropdown, you need to read and send it.

First update the code where you are rendering the link so that it will create an `Id` attribute for the `a` tag, which we can use later in javascript to override the default click behavior.

```
@Html.ActionLink("Add to cart", "AddToCartWithQuantity", "ShoppingCart",
                                  new { id = Model.Id },new { id = "addToCart" } )
```

This will render the anchor tag with id `addToCart`

Now you can have some javascript which listen to the click event on this anchor tag, prevent the default behavior (navigating to the target url) and send the data we want. Here is an example of doing an ajax post

```
$(function (){

    $("#addToCart").click(function (e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var url = $(this).attr("href");
        url = url + '?chosenQuantity=' + $("#ChosenQuantity").val();
        $.post(url).done(function (res){
            if (res.status === "success")
            {
                //update cart UI
                alert(res.cartItemCount);
            }
        });

    });

});
```

Now since we are doing an ajax submit, let's return a JSON response with a status and `cartItemCount` property. Our js code is inspecting this to see whether the action was successful in the ajax call `done` event. Also since we need only the Id and quantity, you do not need to use the `Product` entity as the param. Use a simple `int` type for `Id`

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult AddToCartWithQuantity(int id, int chosenQuantity)
{
    // Your existing code to save. Use id to get the product
    // to do  :replace the hard coded 1 with actual value from db
    return Json(new { status = "success", cartItemCount = 1 });
}
```

Another option is to do a form submit. In that case, Wrap your SELECT and link inside a form element (with it's action set to `/ShoppingCart/AddToCartWithQuantity`) and do a form submit when the link is clicked.

```
<form action='@Url.Action("AddToCartWithQuantity","ShoppingCart")' method='post'>
  <!-- SELECT and Link goes here-->
</form>
```

and the script will be

```
$(function (){

    $("#addToCart").click(function (e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).closest("form").submit();    
    });

});
```

Since our code is doing a full form submit, make sure your action method returns a redirect result back.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult AddToCartWithQuantity(NewProjectModel product, int chosenQuantity)
{
    // Your existing code to save
    return RedirectToAction("Index","ShoppingCart");
}
```

Comment: See for the ActionResult AddToCartWithQuantity, is that the method from the ShoppingCartController? And I'm a bit confused what I've to remove and keep from said method such as where to put the JSON response.

Comment: I did not realize you had 2. Post to the method you want to . If you are posting to the one which has the `return RedirectToAction("Index");` statement, do a form post (second approach in answer) and if you are posting to the other one, use the ajax approach

Comment: I'll try the form submit, I'm confused by what you mean by wrapping my Select and link inside a form element, where do I put that form action and what goes inside it?

Comment: for doing a form submit, your input elements should be inside the form. See the code i have in the answer. replace `<!-- SELECT and Link goes here-->` with your existing code which renders the link and SELECT

Comment: I'm not sure what Select and Link mean, would I have to put this inside the form action?  
    @Html.ActionLink("Add to cart", "AddToCartWithQuantity", 
    "ShoppingCart", new { id = Model.Id}, "")

Comment: you do not know what is "Select" and "a" (anchor/link) element are ? You need to learn the basics of HTML before writing asp.net mvc.

Comment: I havent heard of those terms used before now, by Select did you mean my drop down list and by link do you mean my actionLink?

Comment: yes. SELECT = dropdown. Link= the anchor tag generated by the ActionLink method. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/select

Comment: Keep in mind that,your MVC code (ActionLink method / DropDownListFor method) simply generates HTML markup which browser can understand and render. So your client side code is dealing with that.

Comment: So put both my drop down list and actionlink in the form action?

Comment: Inside the form. You need to learn basics of HTML and how form posting works,

Comment: Well, I did the AJAX solution in my controller and that successfully added the drop down lists' value to the cart. I apologise for my lack of HTML and AJAX knowledge, I've done very little HTML in my college course.

Comment: There is nothing to apologize to me. Internet has tons of resources to learn from. Good luck.